# WCF Data Service - iOS oData SDK Issues

Tags: c#, ios4, odata, wcf-data-services

I have a strange problem relating to a C# WCF Data Service, and a iOS client (using the oData SDK).

Here is a simplified version of my WCF Data Service:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Services;
using System.Data.Services.Common;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using FootballFeedsModel;

[ServiceBehavior]
public class FootballFeeds : DataService<FootballFeedsEntities > {
    // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
        config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("TeamsList", ServiceOperationRights.All);

        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
    }
    [WebGet (ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public IQueryable<Team> TeamsList(){
        return new FootballFeedsEntities().Teams.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

The services is currently hosted live, so I can confirm that I can browse to it, and navigate through the Entity collection etc.

I wrote the following code in my iOS application simply to test the connection to the service:

```
    FootballFeedsEntities *proxy = [[FootballFeedsEntities alloc] 
    initWithUri:@"http://testwebserver.com/Services/FootballFeeds.svc" 
credential:nil];

        DataServiceQuery *query = [proxy teams];

        QueryOperationResponse *response = [query execute];

            resultArray =[[response getResult] retain];

        if([resultArray count] > 0 )
            {
            NSLog(@"Got Results");
        }
```

However the connection simply hangs after I get a 200 status code (there are only 5 items in the database, so I know it is not an issue with the size of the data).

However if I change the code to read from the oData Northwind service, (and add files for this service produced by odatagen)

```
    NorthwindEntities *proxy = [[NorthwindEntities alloc]
 initWithUri:@"http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc"
 credential:nil];

    DataServiceQuery *query = [proxy teams];

    QueryOperationResponse *response = [query execute];

    resultArray =[[response getResult] retain];
    NSLog(@"Got Results");
    if([resultArray count] > 0 )
    {
        NSLog(@"Got Results");
    }
```

I get results as expected.
I am at a loss as to what the missing piece of my jigsaw is, so any pointers would be really helpful.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to my own question, I fixed the code simply by modifying the below, I add here in case anyone else has the same issue.

```
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)] 
public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)     { 
    config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);   
    config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All); 
    config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
 }
```

Comment: what in god's name is that WebGet doing there?